# Not able to Display Data properly in node cli-table

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm trying to display data that i received from an api on console using cli-table. The api call and everything works fine. I'm just having trouble displaying the output. Here's my code

```
const
    url = require('./url'),
    Table = require('cli-table2'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    inquirer = require('inquirer')

let table = new Table({
    head: ['Name', 'Type', 'Language',
        'Genres', 'Status', 'Premiered', 'OfficialSite', 'Schedule', 'Rating', 'Streamed On', 'Externals', 'Images', 'summary'
    ],
    colWidths: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
});

const search = (item) => {

    let shows = []

    url.wordsearch(item)
        .then(result => {

            //console.log(result)
            result.forEach(element => {

                    shows.push({ 'name': element.show['name'], 'value': element.show['id'] })

                })
                //console.log(shows)
            inquirer.prompt([{
                type: 'checkbox',
                message: 'select tvshows you want see',
                name: 'tvshow',
                pageSize: 25,
                choices: shows,
                validate: (answer) => {
                    if (answer.length < 1) {
                        return "You must choose at least one card";
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }]).then((answer) => {
                //console.log(answer)
                printresult(answer)
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

}

const printresult = (answer) => {


    answer.tvshow.forEach(show => {

        url.idsearch(show)
            .then(element => {


                clean(element)

                table.push([element['name'],
                    element['type'],
                    element['language'],
                    element['genres'],
                    element['status'],
                    element['premiered'],
                    element['officialSite'],
                    `Time :${element['schedule']['time']} \n Days: ${element['schedule']['days']}`,
                    element['rating'],
                    ` name:${element['network']['name']}\n Country: ${element['network']['country']}`,
                    `tvrage:${element['externals']['tvrage']}\n thetvdb:${element['externals']['thetvdb']}\n imdb:${element['externals']['imdb']}`,
                    `medium:${element['image']['medium']}\n original:${element['image']['original']}`,
                    element['summary']


                ])

                console.log(table.toString())

            })


    })



}
```

What am I doing wrong ? I want the output in a proper table format with no ... or anything. The printresult method does the work of printing to the console. I'm attaching a screenshot of my output. [image: My output]